# Installing 12.04 Ubuntu Studio on VMware Workstation 7, won't install VMware Tools

Tags: 12.04, installation, vmware, ubuntu-studio, tools

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Studio 12.04 on my laptop by using VMware Workstation 7.1.5, and I've encountered a problem.  The install goes well until the installation of Ubuntu has completed and the installation of VMware Tools starts; after that it just stops.  I have waited about an hour and a half and nothing has changed.

The installation is on VMware Easy Install, and I am running Windows Vista 32-bit with 3 GB system RAM and 2 GB of RAM on the virtual machine.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> install Ubuntu Studio 12.04 on my laptop by using VMware Workstation 7.1.5

The problem is that the VMWare Tools included with 7.1.5 is fairly old at this point and is **not compatible** with the Linux 3.2 kernel that Ubuntu 12.04 runs on. The latest VMWare Workstation is 8.x, and I can confirm that it works fine with Ubuntu 12.04, including VMWare Tools.

Other than upgrading VMWare Workstation to v8.x, you can try the following:

- Install WITHOUT *Easy Install* - it will install OK and you can try installing VMWare Tools later.
- Download and install the latest Tools for Linux for Workstation 7.1.5 on Windows from [here](http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/ws/7.1.5/491717/windows/packages/tools-linux-8.4.8.exe.tar) and see if those install.
- Finally (and note that this is totally unsupported): try the [patch for 7.1.5 here](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/) intended to make it compatible with Linux Kernels 3.2 and 3.3, and then try installing Tools again.

(You can always run `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl` to try to recompile the modules).

Answer (score 1):

1) try to install ubuntu 11.10 on VMWare Workstation 7 (Download ISO , and disable network connection while installing , Setting -> Network )

2) Install VMWare Tool (http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525)

2.1) Take Snap Shot (Just incase update error )

3) and update to 12.04, it should work.

Comment: Don't forget to install offline , disable network connection on ubuntu 11 .

Answer (score 1):

Restore the `/etc/issue` file:

```
sudo mv /etc/issue.backup /etc/issue
```

Restore the /etc/rc.local file:

```
sudo mv /etc/rc.local.backup /etc/rc.local
```

Restore the `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` file:

```
sudo mv /opt/vmware-tools-installer/lightdm.conf /etc/init
```

Then reboot system.